# looking for nudity image filter that can test the adult image from other

Tags: php, image, filter

did any one aware of any new code/program that can filter the adult images being uploaded in website.

to my knowledge i found

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3269.html

now my question is ... is there any other or new image filter that could do the same process?

Comment: a image filter that *can test adult image from other* will not detect pedophilia

Comment: I don't know,  but I suppose implementing one would be a lot of fun. Finally excuse for watching porn :)

Comment: So... the class *calculates* male and female genitalia?

Comment: While I still think that my answer below is the safest way to go, I just found out this: https://nullnude.com/ which seems to cover the original requirement with good percentage of success.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, automatic "skin filters" based on analysis of hues and so on are not the way to go.

If your forum is for adults the most efficient system is having a mechanism allowing users to flag images as "inappropriate". You can manually remove them after inspection or automatically remove them if, say, at least 5 registered users objected to it.

If this is not feasible (ex.: school site where teens or children have access so you can't allow them to see anything before it gets flagged to oblivion) then you have to park uploaded images and have them vetted by you or another administrator before going public.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot rely on an image filter, that's benign. Nothing can accurately analyze an image like that, you'd get tons and tons of false positives and a **lot** of very irritated visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [review](http://www.yangsky.us/products/porndetect/htm/surveypornremoval.htm) of some of your options.

I used to work for a large social network site back in the day. We had a few million registered users and we allowed users to submit text, image and videos to our servers. Porn was an issue for us as well. At the time (about two years ago), I researched the options just like you are doing right now and my result was this: *Free software are not reliable, commercial software are expensive.* This might have changed now but still, a free software relying on "skin detection" will not help you much.

If your company has the budget, then I suggest you research the commercial options. There should be at least a few decent commercial options out there. I remember finding two three companies.

I strongly suggest against using "user complaints" as your first line of defense against nudity. The images need to be checked, somehow, before they go live. You can either do this by automated software, or you can hire some moderators, or you can enlist some volunteers from your users. In any case, make sure the images get checked before they are visible to everyone. Use a "user complaint" system as a second line of defense.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please share the commercial products you found.